# Object.keys(myObject) does not return properties of class in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Why does:

```
let provider = new Provider();
var keys = Object.keys(provider);
console.log(keys);
```

return an empty array, when:

```
let provider = { Name: '', Surname: '' };
var keys = Object.keys(provider);
console.log(keys);
```

returns an array with the 2 properties in it?

Here is my `Provider.ts`:

```
export class Provider {
  public Id: string;
  public Name: string;
  public FriendlyName: string;
  public CompanyRegistrationNumber: string;
  public VatRegistrationNumber: string;
  public TfgUniqueReferenceNumber: string;
  public Since: Date;
  public Until: Date;
  public DefaultBillingDay: number;
  public DefaultProvisioningDay: number;
  public AllowsToProvisionProRata: boolean;
  public AllowsToBillProRata: boolean;
  public EmailAddress: string;
  public DateCreated: Date;
  public DateModified: Date;
  public UserCreated: string;
  public UserModified: string;
  public IsRetired: boolean;
  public ImageUrl: string;
  public ContactNumber1: ContactNumber;
  public ContactNumber2: ContactNumber;
  public PhysicalAddress: Address;
  public PostalAddress: Address;
  public FinancialSystemAccount: FinancialSystemAccount;
  public WholesaleProducts: Array<WholesaleProduct>;
  public ContactPeople: Array<ContactPerson>;
  public Batches: Array<Batch>;
  public BatchCandidates: Array<BatchCandidate>;
  public AllowableBatchTypes: Array<BatchType>;
}
```

Comment: Can you check the content of transpiled script "Provider.js" maybe this is just metadata and doesn't actually generates any props for the object?

Comment: Because those members in your `Provider` class doesn't exists until you define it. If you change one of your property for example `Name` to: `public Name: string = '';` you will see it.

Comment: I thought it might be this.  Is there a way to get those properties without instantiating them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you initialize the properties, they are not actually created. You can check the trasnpiled `Provider.js` file and verify it. It's just a way to tell the compiler that, whenever we *use* it in the instance of `Provider`, force those predefined types.

Test it on the [**Typescript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Provider%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20Id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20Name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20FriendlyName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20CompanyRegistrationNumber%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20VatRegistrationNumber%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20TfgUniqueReferenceNumber%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20Since%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20Until%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20DefaultBillingDay%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20DefaultProvisioningDay%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20AllowsToProvisionProRata%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20AllowsToBillProRata%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20EmailAddress%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20DateCreated%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20DateModified%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20UserCreated%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20UserModified%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20IsRetired%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20ImageUrl%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20InitializedProp%3A%20string%20%3D%20%27%27%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

This class:

```
class Provider {
  public Id: string;
  public Name: string;
  public FriendlyName: string;
  public CompanyRegistrationNumber: string;
  public VatRegistrationNumber: string;
  public TfgUniqueReferenceNumber: string;
  public InitializedProp: string = '';
}
```

Gets transpiled to:

```
var Provider = (function () {
    function Provider() {
        this.InitializedProp = '';
    }
    return Provider;
}());
```

You can see that only the `InitializedProp` is created as a property in the transpiled constructor function.